# Cannot add user with userAdmin or userAdminAnyDatabase priviledges to the admin database

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I am trying to add authentication to my local MongoDB.

In the configuration I have:

```
auth = true
setParameter = enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0
```

I execute the `mongod` server using:

```
/opt/local/bin/mongod --config /Users/gabriel/databases/mongo_data/conf/mongod.conf --setParameter enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0
```

and following [these instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#id1), using the [local exception](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#localhost-exception) I try to add the user:

```
db.addUser({
    user: "username",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ]
})
```

The result is n error:

```
{
    "user" : "username",
    "pwd" : "aa5469a39788b6c3988537cd409887a1",
    "roles" : [
        "userAdminAnyDatabase"
    ],
    "_id" : ObjectId("52a07b1ee11cb128a47b2a1b")
}
Thu Dec  5 14:09:50.373 couldn't add user: not authorized for insert on admin.system.users at src/mongo/shell/db.js:128
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You explicitly forbid localhost authentication when you set `enableLocalhostAuthBypass = 0`. Remove `setParameter = enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0` from configuration and start `mongod` without `--setParameter enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0` and all should work as expected.