# MongoDB out of the box: not authorized for insert (Windows 7)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've been following along with the actual MongoDB docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)
 as well as several tutorial articles that are getting me absolutely nowhere.

Running a 64bit windows OS (which is a work computer, and my particular windows login is not an administrator login.. so I make sure to open any exe files as administrator). I can't do anything in the terminal beyond "mongo" or "use [db name]".

I cannot save or add anything like `db.testData.insert( j )`. Even typing "show dbs", I get an error that says 
`listDatabases failed:{ "ok" :0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:46`

With every example I've followed, I can never seem to be "authenticated" to get past point A. Please help me! I have no idea what I'm doing wrong at this point.

**UPDATE**:
Sorry for the confusion, everyone. The problem turned out to be that I had an old MongoDB service still running in the background that I needed to disable.

The service must have been turned on while I was testing out some node packages or something. Once I disabled the service, everything started working as expected.

**So for those of you who are having trouble, make sure you open up services.msc and make sure nothing is running MongoDB**

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and turning it on again?" - No really. This is a fresh install and you have nothing useful there so delete the installation and any data files. Then re-install. If you notice any other messages doing that then add them to your question

Comment: + Completely fresh install for 64bit windows in C:\mongodb  

+ I create empty directories for C:\data\db  

+ I open mongod.exe as an administrator  

+ I open mongo.exe in a separate terminal and type "use admin". It says "switched to db admin". Everything up to this point is normal  

+ I type any kind of insert or even "show dbs" and I'm constantly being told "not authorized for insert", "not authorized for query", etc.

Comment: I'm trying this with and without a config file as well... In my config file.. i've got: 
`logpath=\mongodb\mongodb.log
dbpath=\mongodb\data\db\
diaglog=3`

Comment: Edit your post. Don't try an go into depth in comments. What we are driving you towards is you **have not** explained **everything** you are doing in your question

Answer (score 0):

As there isn't a formal installer for Windows, I'd recommend you delete the data folder and restart. Out of the box, there is no security in MongoDb, so you've followed a step which later requires a password. Either retrace your steps, or start over.

You don't need to switch to the `admin` Database. I'd suggest you instead switch to a `test` database for example:

```
> use test
switched to db test
```

By default, without extra configuration, on Windows you can delete the contents of `c:\data\db` when MongoDb isn't running (but if you're using a configuration file that specifies the `dbpath`, delete the contents of that folder).

There are a number of [tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-access-control/) with details of how to configure users/security with Mongodb that you may want to read after you've resolved this issue.

There's little reason to create users and administrative control with MongoDB until you gain some experience with the platform. In fact, I wouldn't recommend it at all. It just gets in the way as you're seeing for no real gain.

Comment: This is what I don't understand. I've followed your instructions very closely even before posting this here. I've cleared out C:\data\db numerous times. If you see this thread, I've got the same exact issue as the person in [**this other thread**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401059/cannot-add-user-with-useradmin-or-useradminanydatabase-priviledges-to-the-admin) except none of the suggestions are working.

Comment: @sdawson Do you mean the exact same issue as in you are doing **some** steps to enable authentication? Because that's not what your question  says. Or are you talking about a **fresh** install as you have been pointed to.

Comment: Why are you trying to add authentication? For experiments with MongoDB, just skip those steps. They aren't necessary.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've figured out the problem and will edit the original post to explain.